# android view inflate exception error and java null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I am creating a landscape layout using fragment class. But now my code is showing error in my listMovieActivity file. I tried following some answers from stackoverflow but that didnt help me on it.

This is my listMovieActivity code:

```
    package com.example.moviemanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;


public class listMovieActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private MovieDetailFragment detailFragment = null;
    private MovieListFragment listFragment = null;
    private FragmentManager manager;
    private int selectedItemIndex = -1;
    private String title=null;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listmovie);

        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        detailFragment = (MovieDetailFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.detailmovie_fragment);
        listFragment = (MovieListFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.listmovie_fragment);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            showDetails(selectedItemIndex,title);

    }

    public void showDetails(int selectedItem, String ttl) {
        //Log.d("FRAGMENT", "Selected item " + selectedItem);
        selectedItemIndex = selectedItem;
        title = ttl;
        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            if (detailFragment != null) {
                // update entry
                detailFragment.updateDetails(selectedItem,ttl);
            }
        } else {
            // show DetailsActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailMovie.class);
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", selectedItem);
            intent.putExtra("TITLE", ttl);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


}
```

This is my DatabaseHandler code:

```
    public class DatabaseHandler {
    String cmd;
    private static final String DBTAG = "DatabaseHandler";

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

    public static final String KEY_KEY = "key";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String KEY_STORY = "story";
    public static final String KEY_RATING = "rating";
    public static final String KEY_LANGUAGE = "language";
    public static final String KEY_RUNTIME = "runtime";

    public static final int COL_KEY = 1;
    public static final int COL_TITLE = 2;
    public static final int COL_TYPE = 3;
    public static final int COL_STORY = 4;
    public static final int COL_RATING = 5;
    public static final int COL_LANGUAGE = 6;
    public static final int COL_RUNTIME = 7;

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {
        KEY_ROWID, KEY_KEY, KEY_TITLE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_STORY,
        KEY_RATING, KEY_LANGUAGE, KEY_RUNTIME};

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movieDb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "movieTable";

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + KEY_KEY + " text not null,"
            + KEY_TITLE + " text not null,"
            + KEY_TYPE + " text not null,"
            + KEY_STORY + " text not null,"
            + KEY_RATING + " text not null,"
            + KEY_LANGUAGE + " text not null,"
            + KEY_RUNTIME + " integer not null"
            + ");";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context ctx){
        this.context = ctx;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public DatabaseHandler open(){
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertRow(String mvkey, String mvtitle, String mvtype,
            String mvstory, String mvrating, String mvlanguage, int mvruntime){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_KEY, mvkey);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, mvtitle);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, mvtype);
        initialValues.put(KEY_STORY, mvstory);
        initialValues.put(KEY_RATING, mvrating);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LANGUAGE, mvlanguage);
        initialValues.put(KEY_RUNTIME, mvruntime);

        open();
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        close();
    }

    public void deleteRow(long rowId){
        open();
        cmd = new String ("DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE ( "+KEY_ROWID+" =" + rowId + " );");
        db.execSQL(cmd);
        close();
//      String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
//      return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }

    public void deleteAll(){
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int)rowId));
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    public Cursor getAllRows(){
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c!= null){
            c.moveToFirst();

        }
        return c;
    }

    public Cursor getRow(long rowId){
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c!= null){
            c.moveToFirst();

        }
        return c;
    }

    public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String mvkey, String mvtitle,
            String mvtype, String mvstory, String mvrating,
            String mvlanguage, int mvruntime){
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_KEY, mvkey);
        newValues.put(KEY_TITLE, mvtitle);
        newValues.put(KEY_TYPE, mvtype);
        newValues.put(KEY_STORY, mvstory);
        newValues.put(KEY_RATING, mvrating);
        newValues.put(KEY_LANGUAGE, mvlanguage);
        newValues.put(KEY_RUNTIME, mvruntime);

        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;

    }

    public Cursor listMovieTitle(){
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT "+ KEY_TITLE + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE,null);

    }

    public Cursor get_id(String ttl){
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT "+  KEY_ROWID + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE (" + KEY_TITLE + " = " + ttl + " );",null);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(DBTAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            // Destroy old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the error stack trace i am receiving each time i click on my display button:

```
    04-04 01:00:15.314      811-811/com.example.moviemanager E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-04 01:01:15.098      859-859/com.example.moviemanager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moviemanager/com.example.moviemanager.listMovieActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.example.moviemanager.listMovieActivity.onCreate(listMovieActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.example.moviemanager.DatabaseHandler.open(DatabaseHandler.java:65)
            at com.example.moviemanager.MovieListFragment.onCreateView(MovieListFragment.java:29)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.example.moviemanager.listMovieActivity.onCreate(listMovieActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 01:01:19.447      879-879/com.example.moviemanager E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Previously, I had the same problem error inflating class fragment, but then I solved it by changing my android listview id to android custome list id. But now the problem is appearing again but this time its worst my databasehandler also is showing error it seems. Can any help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

In DatabaseHandler:

```
private final Context context;
```

This makes no sense, the final field cannot be assigned.And how can you make it pass the check?

Put up `MovieListFragment` code, please.